# How can I fix the following error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, database, screen-scraping

I am a few months into programming. I am currently in the process of learning how to automate certain things in a project. My goal is to scrape text, src, and href and store the data in my site's database,but when I try I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'
```

but it does. this is my code. I created a function

```
def get_world_too():
        url = 'http://www.example.com'
        html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')

        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
        entries = [{'href': box.a.get('href'),
                    'src': box.img.get('src'),
                    'text': box.strong.a.text,
                    'url': url
                    } for box in titles]
        return entries
```

then I did this

```
def noindex(request):
    world = get_world_too()

    for entry in world:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry.text
        post.image_url = entry.src
        # post.url = entry.url
        # post.link = entry.href
        # post.description = entry.description
        #
        # d = datetime.datetime(*(entry.published_parsed[0:6]))
        # date_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        #
        # post.publication_date = date_string
        post.save()

        template = "blog/post/noindex.html"
        context = {

        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Isn't the text attribute in my function? Then If I try to comment out text it tells me

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'src'
```

how can I fix this so the data i want get stored in my database without any errors? I'm using django if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to access dictionary keys like this:

```
entry['text']
entry['src']
```

Not like this

```
entry.text
entry.src
```

Answer (score 4):

In python you cannot access dictionary items using the syntax dict.key , 
If entry is a dictionary, you can use

- `entry['key1']`
- `entry.get('key')`